# Entity Framework and SQL Server optimistic concurency support

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

A lot of EF6 guides ([example](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)) recommend to add `rowversion` column to tables (or mark each non-primary-key property with `ConcurrencyCheck` attribute) to implement optimistic concurrency support. But SQL Server supports optimistic concurrency itself (I mean `SNAPSHOT` or `READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT` isolation levels) based on internal versioning mechanisms (transaction sequence number).

I've tested two common scenarios for EF and `SNAPSHOT` level in db (no `rowversion` column or `ConcurrencyCheck` attributes in EF entity):

1. **Tran#1** is updating the data (not committed yet) -> **Tran#2** reads last
   committed version of that data immediately (as expected).
2. **Tran#1** reads the data -> **Tran#2** commits with update -> **Tran#1** commits with update -> `DbUpdateException` is thrown (as expected).

So it works without additional EF stuff. Is it necessary to use `rowversion`/`ConcurrencyCheck`in EF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF does not *require* rowversion. If snapshot isolation is all you need then you're done. In fact EF cannot emulate SNAPSHOT with rowversion because rowversion does not affect reads. Under RC you can read mixed data from multiple writing transactions.

The two consistency models are quite different. Pick what you need.

SNAPSHOT is amazing to get consistent reads without blocking.

Both models are not equivalent to `SERIALIZABLE` which promises as-if-serial execution.

Not even SNAPSHOT plus rowversion is equivalent to `SERIALIZABLE`.

Comment: I still don't quite understand the purpose of adding rowversion/ConcurrencyCheck to model. Is it enough just to set isolation level in db (even in READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT case)?

Comment: "Enough" for what? What amount consistency do you need?

Comment: Sorry if unclear. It's a bit theoretical question: why EF offers to use rowversion/ConcurrencyCheck? Isolation levels are SQL Server feature, and Server doesn't "know" about EF. Why we should "enable" anything in EF settings? For example, if RCSI is set in db, should we set anything in EF model?

Comment: The consistency that SNAPSHOT and EF rowversion provide you are overlapping. There are things that one of the models prevents that the other one doesn't. The question is, therefore, what guaranteed do you like to have at what cost?; rowversion is most targeted at detached operation, I think.; I never use rowversion. I find the existing isolation levels to work well.

Comment: Thanks, I suggested EF uses SQL Server stuff and it was a mistake! Now I understand that EF and SQL Server have different and completely independent implementations of optimistic concurrency.